# Como almacenar datos tipo string en un arreglo en java

Tags: java, string, array, impresión, almacenamiento

Buenas Gente necesito ayuda, estoy trabajando un proyecto con formularios, el programa ya esta hecho, trata sobre un cuestionario en el cual presenta una pregunta (jlabel) y el usuario elige una de las opciones que se muestran mediante (radiobutton), hasta que el sistema incida en una respuesta final.

Lo que quiero es agregarle un boton el cual me imprima en un textarea el recorrido de las preguntas  que se hicieron para llegar a dicha respuesta. Ejm.

```
  pregunta1

  pregunta4

  pregunta5

  pregunta6

  respuesta
```

***Suponiendo que esas fueron las preguntas a las que el usuario respondio "Si".***

ok disculpen soy nuevo, en fin si me pudieran ayudar lo que quiero es crear un boton que al presionarlo me imprima el recorrido de un arbol. pero necesito saber como almacenar un dato tipo string de forma generica y luego imprimirlos en un textarea. Gracias!

Gracias **@David** Me funciono siempre tu conocimiento, ahora tengo una duda, cuando hago la impresion de la informacion, me imprime los datos separados por **","** y encerrado entre **"[ ]"** como puedo omitir esos caracteres?? ***Ejm: [Rojo,Verde,Azul,Gris]***, pero lo que realmente quiero es esto -->

```
Rojo
Verde
Azul
Gris
```

Tambien quisiera que me ayuden en como saber si un boton ha sido presionado, intente usando una variable tipo boolean inicializando en false y dentro del Mousclicked del botn colocarla true, pero como hago para reinicializarla a false.

Comment: Pon el código que tienes para saber que podría ser el error.

Comment: No será que solamente te falta importar la librería adecuada? `Java.utils.ArrayList`. Tema aparte, el código que pusiste como "respuesta" debería ir en la pregunta que formulaste; lo revise y en ningún lado vi que declarabas un arreglo de tipo `string`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: si necesitas agregar informacion para aclarar usa el boton [edit]

Comment: tambien por favor mira [mcve]. necesitamos ubicar tu problema mas rapidademente que viendo montones de lineas de codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es almacenar valores de tipo String en un Arreglo, es tan sencillo como lo siguiente:

**Array**

```
// Aqui los valores se introducen al declarar el arreglo.
String[] frutas = {"mango", "uva", "pera", "manzana"};

// Aqui los valores se introducen despues de declarar el arreglo. 
// Este es un arreglo de 4 posiciones, el numero de elementos que puede  
// almacenar se declara en la instancia de este.
String[] nombres = new String[4];
nombres[0] = "Jose";
nombres[1] = "Pedro";
nombres[2] = "Juan";
nombres[3] = "Rafael";
```

**ArrayList**

Recuerda importar la libreria:

```
import java.utils.ArrayList;
```

.

```
ArrayList<String> lacteos = new ArrayList<String>();

lacteos.add("Leche");
lacteos.add("Mantequilla");
lacteos.add("Queso");
lacteos.add("Yogour");
```

Una de las diferencia entre un ArrayList y un Array, es que un ArrayList puede almacenar valores de manera dinámica, por lo que no es necesario definir el número de posiciones que este poseerá al declararlo. Otra de las diferencias es que un ArrayList posee métodos que permiten manipular las listas con mas facilidad.